# LWC - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.detail.value')

Tags: lightning-web-components

It is suddenly giving me this error

> TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'e.detail.value').

Functions are all working, but throwing me this error. Any idea of why and how I'm going to fix this problem?

.html

```html
<template>
    <lightning-checkbox-group name="CheckboxGroup"
                          label="choose one"
                          data-id="checkbox"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          onchange={handleInputVal} required></lightning-checkbox-group>
    <lightning-input type="checkbox" label="None of the above" value="none" onchange={handleUncheck}></lightning-input>
</template>
```

js.

```js
 get options() {
   return [
     { label: "1", value: "1" },
     { label: "2", value: "2" },
     { label: "3", value: "3" },
   ];
 }

 value = [];
 userChoice = [];

 handleInputVal(e) { // capturing option value
   this.value = e.detail.value;
   this.userConditionsLWC1 = [];
   this.userConditionsLWC1.push(this.value);
   this.omniApplyCallResp({ userConditionsLWC1: this.userConditionsLWC1 });
 }

   handleUncheck(e) { // none of the above - disable, read-only & capturing "none" value
     this.template.querySelector('[data-id="checkbox"]').disabled = e.target.checked;
     this.value = [];
     this.userConditionsLWC1 = [];
     this.userConditionsLWC1.push("None of the above");
     this.omniApplyCallResp({ userConditionsLWC1: this.userConditionsLWC1 });
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

There is actually another issue here, and it's a bit sneaky.

When you write to `this.value` you are assigning that value an array.

```
this.value = e.detail.value;
this.userConditionsLWC1 = [];
this.userConditionsLWC1.push(this.value);
```

Then, when you `push` to the `userConditionsLWC1` array, you are adding this array as an element of the parent array. You end up with:

```
[['value1','value2']]
```

You need to de-reference the `value` array before you add it to the second one.

Try changing the last line above to:

```
this.userConditionsLWC1.push(...this.value);
```

This will destructure the array to it's component parts and you will end up with your target array containing:

```
['value1','value2']
```

As expected.

**OLD BELOW (may still be relevant)**
I think you have put the component in a state that it's not designed to handle.

You have set `required` to true, but then also provided a way of unsetting all values (via `handleUncheck`).

This makes the component's internal state inconsistent, so it's sending you a null detail on change. It should probably handle that, but I think the way around this is not not provide an uncheck all function, if you are are going to make this `lightning-checkbox-group` `required`.

Either that, or uncheck all but one of the options in this method.

Comment: Hey, @Caspar Harmer thanks for the help. I just removed the required and still gives me the same Type error. And do you know how to wrap all of them in a required?

Comment: hey this is the additional follow up. I just initially removed handleInputVal and handleuncheck just to see what shows up. and found out it's still giving me an Type error but saying (evaluating 't.apply'), which I don't recognize at all. Any idea?